# Windows application using python and c++

Tags: python, c++, windows

I want to start working on my own windows software. I know python and I am learning c++. How can I create windows software with the frontend written in c++ and the backend in python?
I know this is possible because blender is written in c++ and python aswell

Comment: You've got a big issue.  The Python language is interpreted and requires an interpreter to function.  The C++ language compiles to native code.  Python can call C++ code.  Having C++ application call Python code is more difficult.

IMHO, stay with one language.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews The reason I want/need to use both is becouse python isn't that good for the frontend and c++ isn't the best for backend

Comment: Your question may be downvoted because it sounds like you are requesting a tutorial.  Tutorials or instructions can be too long for a Stack Overflow answer.  Also people would like to see code and questions about code.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews I am not asking for a tutorial but I am asking for a guide line so I can find tutorials

Comment: read the tutorial from the cpython docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html#:~:text=Very%20High%20Level%20Embedding,some%20operation%20on%20a%20file.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can embed Python into C++.

[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html#:%7E:text=Very%20High%20Level%20Embedding,some%20operation%20on%20a%20file.)

The simplest form of embedding Python is the use of the very high level interface. This interface is intended to execute a Python script without needing to interact with the application directly. This can for example be used to perform some operation on a file.

```
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    wchar_t *program = Py_DecodeLocale(argv[0], NULL);
    if (program == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: cannot decode argv[0]\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    Py_SetProgramName(program);  /* optional but recommended */
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
                    "print('Today is', ctime(time()))\n");
    if (Py_FinalizeEx() < 0) {
        exit(120);
    }
    PyMem_RawFree(program);
    return 0;
}
```